# Immutable.fromJS() is not deep

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

The description of `Immutable.fromJS` is:

> Deeply converts plain JS objects and arrays to Immutable Maps and Lists.

But that's wrong. I have an object with the following structure. The capitalized items are ES6 classes.

```
Foo
  prop1
  prop2
  bars
    Bar
      prop1
      prop2
    Bar
      prop1
      prop2
  bazes
    Baz
      prop1
      prop2
      bars
        Bar
          prop1
          prop2
        Bar
          prop1
          prop2
    Baz
      prop1
      prop2
      bars
        Bar
          prop1
          prop2
        Bar
          prop1
          prop2
```

The result of `Immutable.fromJS(foo)` is a Map. The arrays `bars` and `bazes` are `List`s. However, each element of these lists is still a plain (ES6) object. The `bars` property of each Baz is an array, not a list.

Am I doing something wrong, or is the documentation incorrect?

Maybe the deep feature is not supported for ES6 objects? If that's the case, how can I make my object deeply immutable?

UPDATE:

This works but feels kinda gross: `Immutable.fromJS(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(foo)))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The very first sentence in the [docs for `fromJS`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/fromJS) is:

> Deeply converts plain JS objects and arrays to Immutable Maps and Lists.

If Foo, Bar, and Baz are ES6 classes then they are neither plain JS objects nor arrays—they're instances of a class. So, no, the docs are not incorrect.

As an aside, if `Immutable.fromJS` automatically converted any object it encountered into a plain JS object, as you seem to have expected it to, that would be very surprising behavior to most users, and not at all desirable.

But since that's the behavior you want, you'll be happy to know that the Immutable wiki has [a section on this exact topic](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/wiki/Converting-from-JS-objects#custom-conversion), which I'll duplicate here for posterity:

> Here is an example which will convert any Object, including exotic
>   Objects, to `Immutable.Map`:
>
> ```
> function fromJSGreedy(js) {
>   return typeof js !== 'object' || js === null ? js :
>     Array.isArray(js) ? 
>       Immutable.Seq(js).map(fromJSGreedy).toList() :
>       Immutable.Seq(js).map(fromJSGreedy).toMap();
> }
> ```

That's pretty simple. And, indeed, it works exactly as promised, as you can see by running the below snippet.

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(name, ...children) {
    this.name = name;
    this.children = children;
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {}
class Baz extends Foo {}

const myBar = new Bar("myBar", new Baz("myBaz1"), new Baz("myBaz2"));
const myFoo = new Foo("myFoo", myBar);

function fromJSGreedy(js) {
  return typeof js !== 'object' || js === null ? js :
    Array.isArray(js) ? 
      Immutable.Seq(js).map(fromJSGreedy).toList() :
      Immutable.Seq(js).map(fromJSGreedy).toMap();
}

console.log(fromJSGreedy(myFoo).toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.js"></script>
```

Comment: Works great, thanks. I think the docs could be clearer. From developers in every other language I've worked with "plain" means typed objects (POJO, POCO, PORO, etc). Objects that do not derive from classes are called "anonymous." Perhaps the JS community, with proper classes being new and "exotic" has not yet adopted this common terminology.

Comment: As regards surprise, what ```Immutable.fromJS``` does is to shallowly convert an ES6 object to a Map but not covert any nested ES6 objects. That seems quite surprising. It would seem to be far less surprising if it converted nothing, especially since the description says "deeply."

Comment: If by "ES6 object" you mean "instance of an ES6 class," then I cannot reproduce the behavior you describe. For example, the code `class Foo {}; console.log(Immutable.fromJS(new Foo).constructor);` in Node.js produces the output `[Function: Foo]`, (showing that it's an instance of Foo, not Immutable.Map), whereas the code `console.log(Immutable.fromJS({}).constructor)` prints `{ [Function: Map] of: [Function], isMap: [Function: isMap] }`.

Comment: You can see the same behavior in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jkckcjxr/ (run it with your console open). `Immutable.fromJS` does not "shallowly convert an [instance of an ES6 class] to a Map."

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, I had to check for `Date` types because this function was converting my dates into non-date objects. This function uses typescript and lodash, but I'm sure you can alter it accordingly

```
export function myFromJS(js: any): any {
  return typeof js !== 'object' || js === null || (_.isDate(js)) ? js :
    Array.isArray(js) ?
      Immutable.Seq(js).map(myFromJS).toList() :
      Immutable.Seq(js).map(myFromJS).toMap();
}
```