# Immutable.js fromJS() is not returning an immutable object

Tags: typescript, immutable.js

I'm using `"immutable": "^3.8.1",` in my redux store (ngrx). I know that it's installed because I have successfully converted my stated into an immutable object

```
const immState = Imm.fromJS(state);
```

[image]

But I hit an issue when I tried to delete a deeply nested item with this command:

```
return immState.deleteIn(['days', dayKey, 'userMeals', state.focus_user], meal._id);
```

Immutable.js is throwing an error when it hits `'userMeals'` and upon further investigation, it seems that `Imm.fromJS()` is not converting a deeply nest object into an immutable structure. In the image below I try to access that property directly, but it is still not converting it into an immutable object.

[image]

Is this somehow the expected behavior or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40661729/immutable-fromjs-is-not-deep/44148628#44148628). Apparently ES6 classes give `immutable.js` issues, surprisingly. there are solutions though.